# Silverstripe 4.1 public folder 404

Tags: silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I just started to try to make a theme in Silverstripe 4.1. The 4.1 version has a new feature where some of the resources are copied to the public folder (css files and image files).

My problem is that the syncing seems to not work very well, I get 404 issues when trying to include the css files or the image files in a page. Even when I can see that the files have been copied to the public folder.

**Am I supposed to use the public folder during development of a theme or is that something to use when making an actual deployment?**

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here if someone else is frustrated over this. There is actually a tutorial which explains this:

https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/v4/creating-your-first-project